# Concatinate in OPEN OFFICE removing Leading zeroes

Tags: openoffice-calc, leading-zero, openoffice-basic

```
  A        B            C   D

2 DRUGS 000000000004    2   PARACETAMOL (ACETAMINOPHEN)  TAB 500 MG
```

This is my entry in my open office so we have here the row 2 with columns A-D
I have create a formula `=CONCATENATE("('" ;A2;"','";B2;"','";C2;"','";D2;"'),")`

and this one give me this result:

> ('DRUGS','4','2','PARACETAMOL (ACETAMINOPHEN)  TAB 500 MG'),

Basically I want a result like:

> ('DRUGS','000000000004','2','PARACETAMOL (ACETAMINOPHEN)  TAB 500 MG'),

Column B is set to Number with Leading zeroes set to 12.

What I want is to get a result where the leading zeroes in column B is will retained.

Answer (score 1):

```
=CONCATENATE("('" ;A2;"','";TEXT(B2;"000000000000");"','";C2;"','";D2;"'),")
```

Use any mask you want as the second parameter to the `TEXT` function

More on `TEXT` and other text functions: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=CONCATENATE("('";A2;"','";REPT("0";12-LEN(B2));B2;"','";C2;"','";D2;"'),")
```

I suspect what you have in B2 is `4` formatted with many leading `0`. If so, it is possible, assuming many other entries, that some will be text and the cell content actually something like `000000000004` - for which the above formula will not work (but yours should).